# Blazor WASM animated gif flickering on mobile PWA

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, animated-gif

I am trying to show animated GIFs during loading of the app and the Pages.
Unfortunately, the ~500KB GIF is not played smoothly, but flickers.

My `FooPage.razor`:

```
@if (_showLoader)
{
   <LoadingComponent />
}

...

bool _showLoader = true;

@code
{
   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   { 
      await LongLoadingOperation();
      _showLoader = false;
   }
}
```

My `index.html`:

```
<div id="app">
   <div>
      <img src="img/animation.gif" />
   </div>    
</div>
```

My `LoadingComponent.razor`:

```
@_renderLoader

@code {
    private RenderFragment _renderLoader = __builder =>
    {
        <div>
             <img src="img/animation.gif" />    
        </div>
    };
}
```

It's even worse when I place the `LoadingComponent`-HTML into the `index.html` to show the animated GIF while the App is loading.

This behaviour also tends to occur on mobile devices, on the PC the flickering is not noticeable.

Have I overlooked something?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do with the `RenderFragment` that you can't just do by declaring the object in markup.

Comment: I do this to reuse rendering logic without overhead, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0). As stated in my question, it's flickering in both cases, using `RenderFragment` and using markup.

Comment: Okay, it's nice that you've learned that, but don't use it unless you need to, which you probably never will: "`You should only be concerned about skipping the rerendering subtrees that are particularly expensive to render and are causing UI lag.` (from your linked page)"  Anyway, once html markup goes out to the client browser, then it's basically up to the browser to load and animate your .gif.  So I'd guess either you are accidentally forcing some kind of reload, or the .gif itself is faulty.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Since I am experiencing a UI lag, I thought it would be exact use case. I am not actively forcing a reload, and the gif is not faulty, since it runs smoothly on PC.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yeah that sounds like the way to do it, but I am already awaiting the LongOperation. Should I await another Task.Delay before, inside, after? And do you have an idea why it might fix the issue?

Comment: You would have to get some Delay() _inside_ the LongOperation, evenly spread. I'm not sure if it will fix the issue, you can try a mock-up.

Comment: @osiki96, I think Henk is saying the Delay will yield the thread to the UI, so the single UI thread can update your gif.  What exactly does your `LongLoadingOperation()` currently do?  If it's an uninterrupted time-waster, then try breaking it down.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I have multiple `LoadingOperations`, which are awaited API Calls. In between, I have a couple operations on the received data (calculating sums etc.). I have seen Hank proposing to run Task.Delay calls now and then while scrolling through SO, but I can not imagine that it should be that hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for sharing their thoughts. I gained a couple more insights about Blazor WASM restrictions.

Surprisingly, upgrading the project to .NET6 fixed the issue. There was no more flickering, neither in the browser nor in the PWA on the tested iOS mobile devices.